# codefights square digits sequence(python)

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning to code, and presently trying to solve a problem on codefights;

Consider a sequence of numbers a0, a1, ..., an, in which an element is equal to the sum of squared digits of the previous element. The sequence ends once an element that has already been in the sequence appears again.

Given the first element a0, find the length of the sequence.

Input/Output

[time limit] 4000ms (py3)
[input] integer a0

First element of a sequence, positive integer.

Guaranteed constraints:
1 ≤ a0 ≤ 650.

[output] integer
And here is my code:

def value(a):

```
for i in str(a):
    val = val + i**2

return val
```

def squareDigitsSequence(a0):

```
a=a0    
while (a not in list) is True:

    for i in len(str(a)):
        b=value(a)
        list.append(b)
        a=b
return len(list)
```

But I am getting this error:
while (a not in list) is True:
TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable.
How can I solve this?

Comment: You cannot name your list `list` because it is a built-in type. You have to use a different name.

Comment: Technically you _can_ use the name `list`, but it's a bad idea. I don't think that's actually the problem here, though. The problem is that he didn't actually initialize `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As glibdud pointed out, you haven't initialized a list variable (and it's a bad idea to call it `list`). Also, `val` is not defined in your other function. Additionally, in your second function, you may get an unsupported operand error, since you are squaring a string, rather than an integer, and appending it to the undefined variable.

Try this instead:

```
def squareDigitsSequence(a0):
    # the list in which you'll store the elements you've seen, starting with a0
    used_elements = [a0]

    # I chose to break out of the while loop and return something when a duplicate
    # was found

    while True:
        temp_val = value(used_elements[-1])

        # here the duplicate is not included
        if temp_val in used_elements:
            return len(used_elements)
        else:
            used_elements.append(temp_val)

def value(b):
    sum = 0

    # convert string representation of each digit to int and square them, add to sum
    for char in str(b):
        sum += int(char) ** 2

    return sum
```

This returns 1 when a0 is 1, as the used_elements list would be just `[1]`, and 9 when `a0` is 2, since `used_elements` will be `[2, 4, 16, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20]` as it should, since the sum of squares of the digits of 20 is 4, which is already in the list. Feel free to try other values of `a0`, and let me know if you need some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

My code passed all test cases:-

```
def squareDigitsSequence(a0):
    seq = [a0]
    while seq[-1] not in seq[:-1]:
        seq.append(sum(int(i)**2 for i in str(seq[-1])))
    return len(seq)
```